# How to change a timeout for the wait in Frameworkium - globally

Tags: timeout, wait

I would like to change a default timout for a wait in Frameworkium to a bit bigger.
I do not want to do it with Selenium nor any other 'workarounds' - I would like to change it in the Frameworkium as I can see it exists in the class: BaseUITest, line 39:
private static final Duration 
`DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = Duration.of(10, SECONDS);`

Any idea?

I was going through many pages but can't find specific Frameworkium setup

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(_element_));
```

I'd like to have, let say 30 second here, globally, for any condition

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

```
PageFactory.newInstance(Class<T> clazz, Duration timeout)
```

or

```
new MyPage().get(Duration timeout)
```